# Disqus API, trying to make some calls from localhost

Tags: api, localhost, disqus

And have added localhost in the allowed domains in the API configuration, but when I am making the calls I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listPosts.json?forum=my_forum&api_key=my_public_key. Origin http://localhost:4567 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Did you try setting the configuration variable disqus_developer = 1